# Not able to read from Tweets from twitter

Tags: python-3.x, docker, twitter, tweepy, kafka-producer-api

I am trying to read tweets having specific keywords using docker. I have taken reference from
[Github link](https://github.com/youheekil/Twitter-Streaming-with-Apache-Kafka-Docker-and-Python/blob/main/src/producer.py) .

I have made some minor changes. While I'm trying to execute I am facing issues with a number of arguments through all the details in place. It would be great if anybody can guide me where I'm doing wrong

```
### twitter
import tweepy
from tweepy.auth import OAuthHandler
from tweepy import Stream
#from tweepy.streaming import StreamListener
import json
import logging 


### logging 
FORMAT = "%(asctime)s | %(name)s - %(levelname)s - %(message)s"
LOG_FILEPATH = "C:\\docker-kafka\\log\\testing.log"
logging.basicConfig(
    filename=LOG_FILEPATH,
    level=logging.INFO,
    filemode='w',
    format=FORMAT)

### Authenticate to Twitter
with open('C:\\docker-kafka\\credential.json','r') as f:
    credential = json.load(f)

CONSUMER_KEY = credential['twitter_api_key']
CONSUMER_SECRET = credential['twitter_api_secret_key']
ACCESS_TOKEN = credential['twitter_access_token']
ACCESS_TOKEN_SECRET = credential['twitter_access_token_secret']
BEARER_TOKEN = credential['bearer_token']



#from tweepy.streaming import StreamListener
from tweepy import OAuthHandler
from tweepy import Stream
from kafka import KafkaProducer
producer = KafkaProducer(bootstrap_servers='localhost:9092',
    value_serializer=lambda v: v.encode('utf-8')) #Same port as your Kafka server


topic_name = "docker-twitter"


class twitterAuth():
    """SET UP TWITTER AUTHENTICATION"""

    def authenticateTwitterApp(self):
        auth = OAuthHandler(consumer_key=CONSUMER_KEY, consumer_secret=CONSUMER_SECRET)
        auth.set_access_token(ACCESS_TOKEN, ACCESS_TOKEN_SECRET)

        return auth



class TwitterStreamer():

    """SET UP STREAMER"""
    def __init__(self):
        self.twitterAuth = twitterAuth()

    def stream_tweets(self):
        while True:
            listener = ListenerTS() 
            auth = self.twitterAuth.authenticateTwitterApp()
            stream = Stream(auth, listener)
            stream.filter(track=["Starbucks"], stall_warnings=True, languages= ["en"])


class ListenerTS(tweepy.Stream):

    def on_status(self, status):
        tweet = json.dumps({
            'id': status.id, 
            'text': status.text, 
            'created_at': status.created_at.strftime("%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S")
        }, default=str)  

        producer.send(topic_name, tweet)
        return True


if __name__ == "__main__":
    TS = TwitterStreamer()
    TS.stream_tweets()
```

[image]

Comment: Are you sure the authentication part is working? as far as i understand, the error is telling you that `tweepy.Stream` that you instantiated in ListenerTS is not receiving its arguments to init (the keys)

I would try to pass this keys as arguments and verify if the authentication part is workiing correctly, because all points to this.

Comment: I just tested it and its working fine

Comment: what if you try to pass those keys as arguments to StreamListener?

Comment: from tweepy docs:

import tweepy

stream = tweepy.Stream(
    "Consumer Key here", "Consumer Secret here",
    "Access Token here", "Access Token Secret here"
)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to resolve the issue by adding the secrets but got a different error.

```
def stream_tweets(self):
    while True:
        listener = ListenerTS(CONSUMER_KEY,CONSUMER_SECRET,ACCESS_TOKEN,ACCESS_TOKEN_SECRET) 
        listener.filter(track=["Starbucks"], stall_warnings=True, languages= ["en"])
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Answer reference:

[Not able to read from Tweets from twitter](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74523513/not-able-to-read-from-tweets-from-twitter?noredirect=1#comment131552226_74523513)

As far as i understand, the class `tweepy.Stream` needs to be initialized, even if inheriting it. So, instead of:

try

```py
class ListenerTS(tweepy.Stream):
    def __init__(self):
        tweepy.Stream.__init__(self, CONSUMER_KEY, CONSUMER_SECRET, ACCESS_TOKEN, ACCESS_TOKEN_SECRET)
```

Also check this docs:
https://docs.tweepy.org/en/stable/streaming.html

And maybe this link:
https://improveandrepeat.com/2022/04/python-friday-117-streaming-search-results-with-tweepy/

Comment: I made the change but still the issue with position argument is present

Comment: how does your code look now?

Comment: I copy pasted yours with the above

Comment: following the tutorial, listenerTs should inherit StreamListener, not Stream
https://github.com/youheekil/Twitter-Streaming-with-Apache-Kafka-Docker-and-Python/blob/main/src/producer.py#L70

Comment: Pls Check the error, and that's the reason I have changed it to Tweepy.Stream

Comment: oh, i see. Are you using tweepy v4?

Comment: Added some reference links and tweepy docs about stream class on v4. Take a look and try that, if it doesnt work reply here